# nodes in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, lucene, nosql, elasticsearch

So I'm getting started with Elasticsearch, and I created a few nodes on my machine using:

```
elasticsearch -Des.node.name=Node-2
```

Now, as far as I understand a `node` is another machine/server on a cluster, you can correct me if I'm wrong, now.

1.In order to add nodes to a cluster you need these machines to be on the same network? can I have a node in US and another node in the EU as part of the same structure? Or do they need to be in the same building, same network.

2.What is the idea with nodes? to split the data on multiple machines/nodes and also split power to calculate certain querys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. By default ElasticSearch looks for nodes running the same same clustername on the same network. If you want to configure things differently take a look at http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-discovery-zen.html
2. The idea to to split data across multiple machines in case it doesn't fit one one machine AND to prevent data loss in case a node fails (by default all data is replicated 3 times) AND to split query computation power. (ElasticSearch automatically splits your query into query's for all separate nodes, and aggregates the results).

Hope this answers your questions :)

Comment: Good answer! If I may add a small note, having machines that are too far apart in the same cluster is not usually a great idea due to network latency.